# Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently getting request time out for my JSP application when I run it on google app engine. This is due to the 30 seconds respond time.

Since my application request takes some time, I discovered I am required to send multiple request to the servlet from the JSP page to resolve this issue of request time out.

Is there any way I could resolve this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to increase 30 sec timeout. There is something wrong with the design if you application take such amount of time to process request. Try to play with TaskQueue API.